# how to append just 1 element of 4 to another div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, append

Hello I am a student learning jQuery and my goal is to move the element (just that single character) clicked to a specified '#chosen' div area and the rest to remain (as I will be adding a second selecting option after this step). However, when one of the characters is clicked, all of the characters move to that '#chosen' div. I know my code is wrong and unfinished, but I am just unsure how to fix it or how to split up the elements because they all have the same class. Thank you for any help or hints in advanced I really appreciate it.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Audio
// var audioElement = $('audio');
//  audioElement.attr('src', 'assets/mp3/cantina.mp3');
//  audioElement.attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
//  audioElement.loop = true; 

//Objects
var hansolo = {
    name: "Han Solo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/hansolo.jpg",
}

var chewy = {
    name: "Chewy",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/chewy.jpg",
}

var jabba = {
    name: "Jabba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/jabba.jpg",
}

var greedo = {
    name: "Greedo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/greedo.jpg",
}

var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, greedo];

var charOptionsRow = $('#charOptions');
    $.each(choices, function(index, choice) {
      // Create a new div.col-lg-3 to be appended to row.
      var charOptionCol = $('<div>')
        .addClass('char-option col-lg-3');

      // Append image to col.
      var charImg = $('<img>')
        .addClass('char-img')
        .attr('src', choice.src);
      charOptionCol.append(charImg);

      // Append text to col.
      var charText = $('<h3>')
        .addClass('char-text')
        .text(choice.name);
      charOptionCol.append(charText);

      // Append column to row.
      charOptionsRow.append(charOptionCol);
});

$(document).on('click', '.char-img', 'char-text', function() {
    if (hansolo) {
        var charPick =$("#chosen");
        $('.char-img').appendTo(charPick);
        $('.char-text').appendTo(charPick);
    }
    if (chewy) {
        var charPick =$("#chosen");
        $('.char-img').appendTo(charPick);
        $('.char-text').appendTo(charPick);
    }
    if (jabba) {
        var charPick =$("#chosen");
        $('.char-img').appendTo(charPick);
        $('.char-text').appendTo(charPick);
    }
    if (greedo) {
        var charPick =$("#chosen");
        $('.char-img').appendTo(charPick);
        $('.char-text').appendTo(charPick);
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JQuery Game</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
        <h1 align="center">Star Wars Game</h1>
        <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:</h2>
        <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
        </div>

        <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
            <!-- Choice Header -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 you" id="chosen" align="center">
                <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">You</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- First Enemy Header -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 fighting" align="center">
                <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">Fighting</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
            <!-- Enemies Header-->
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="enemies" align="center">
                <h2 align="center" id="enemies-text" class="hidden">Your Enemies</h2>
            </div>
        </div>  
            <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
            <!-- Enemies -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
                    <div id="first-enemy"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
                    <div id="second-enemy"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
                    <div id="third-enemy"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

<script src="assets/js/game.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're moving all the `char-img` and `char-text` items (barring a few typos) at once -- references to `$('.char-img')` don't know that you mean just the one that was clicked.

Instead, use `this` to tell you which element was clicked. Then, grab the adjacent text or image, and move *just* those two.

```
$(document).on('click', '.char-img, .char-text', function() {
  var el = $(this),
      img, txt;

  if (el.hasClass('char-img')) {
    img = el;
    txt = el.next('.char-text');
  } else {
    txt = el;
    img = el.prev('.char-img');
  }

  $('#chosen').append(img).append(txt);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Objects
  var hansolo = {
    name: "Han Solo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/hansolo.jpg",
  }

  var chewy = {
    name: "Chewy",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/chewy.jpg",
  }

  var jabba = {
    name: "Jabba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/jabba.jpg",
  }

  var greedo = {
    name: "Greedo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "assets/images/greedo.jpg",
  }

  var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, greedo];

  var charOptionsRow = $('#charOptions');
  $.each(choices, function(index, choice) {
    // Create a new div.col-lg-3 to be appended to row.
    var charOptionCol = $('<div>')
      .addClass('char-option col-lg-3');

    // Append image to col.
    var charImg = $('<img>')
      .addClass('char-img')
      .attr('src', choice.src);
    charOptionCol.append(charImg);

    // Append text to col.
    var charText = $('<h3>')
      .addClass('char-text')
      .text(choice.name);
    charOptionCol.append(charText);

    // Append column to row.
    charOptionsRow.append(charOptionCol);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.char-img, .char-text', function() {
    var el = $(this),
      img, txt;
      
    if (el.hasClass('char-img')) {
      img = el;
      txt = el.next('.char-text');
    } else {
      txt = el;
      img = el.prev('.char-img');
    }

    $('#chosen').append(img).append(txt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
  <h1 align="center">Star Wars Game</h1>
  <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:</h2>
  <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
  </div>

  <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
    <!-- Choice Header -->
    <div class="col-lg-6 you" id="chosen" align="center">
      <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">You</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- First Enemy Header -->
    <div class="col-lg-6 fighting" align="center">
      <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">Fighting</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
    <!-- Enemies Header-->
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="enemies" align="center">
      <h2 align="center" id="enemies-text" class="hidden">Your Enemies</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
    <!-- Enemies -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
      <div id="first-enemy"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
      <div id="second-enemy"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
      <div id="third-enemy"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: oh of course! I forgot about using 'this'...thanks Paul I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for "$(document).on(...", listen for $(".char-option").on("click", function() .... - then, inside the function, $(this) will be the element that was clicked on. Instead of listening for a click anywhere, this will allow you to listen for click events just on elements that have the "char-option" class.

In your if statement, all of those will resolve to true. I understand the intent is "if hansolo was clicked then", but you're really asking "if hansolo is not undefined".

While I haven't provided everything for you, hopefully this will help get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: this is very helpful Todd, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

In the click event, instead of using `$('.char-img')` selector, try using `$(this)`.

Also, you don't need to check who was chosen if you're going to run the same piece of code in every `if` statement.

See if this works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Audio
  // var audioElement = $('audio');
  //  audioElement.attr('src', 'assets/mp3/cantina.mp3');
  //  audioElement.attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  //  audioElement.loop = true; 

  //Objects
  var hansolo = {
    name: "Han Solo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/7b72d15a85bf468d8af9c5b5699e02ca.png",
  };

  var chewy = {
    name: "Chewy",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/044c70c30f084ba095c35aa7e4451f0c.png",
  };

  var jabba = {
    name: "Jabba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/458ccfc9819f4f8b85116b81584f4eea.png",
  };

  var boba = {
    name: "Boba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/85458d08609f4170b5b8cdda58fca07c.png",
  };

  var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, boba];

  var charOptionsRow = $('#charOptions');
  $.each(choices, function(index, choice) {
    // Create a new div.col-lg-3 to be appended to row.
    var charOptionCol = $('<div>')
      .addClass('char-option col-lg-3');

    // Append image to col.
    var charImg = $('<img>')
      .addClass('char-img')
      .attr('src', choice.src);
    charOptionCol.append(charImg);

    // Append text to col.
    var charText = $('<h3>')
      .addClass('char-text')
      .text(choice.name);
    charOptionCol.append(charText);

    // Append column to row.
    charOptionsRow.append(charOptionCol);
  });

  $('.char-option').on('click', function() {
    var $charPick = $("#chosen");
    var $chosen = $('#chosen-text');
    var $img = $(this).find('img').clone();
    var $header = $(this).find('h3').clone();
    var name = $header.text();

    $chosen.children('span').html(name);
    $chosen.removeClass('hidden');

    $charPick.find('img').remove();
    $charPick.find('h3').remove();
    $charPick.append($img).append($header);

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#chosen .char-img {
   border: 0.2em solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JQuery Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
    <h1 align="center">Star Wars Game</h1>
    <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:</h2>
    <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Choice Header -->
      <div class="col-lg-6 you" id="chosen" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">You've chosen <span class="chosen-name"></span></h2>
      </div>
      <!-- First Enemy Header -->
      <div class="col-lg-6 fighting" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">Fighting</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Enemies Header-->
      <div class="col-lg-12" id="enemies" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="enemies-text" class="hidden">Your Enemies</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Enemies -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="first-enemy"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="second-enemy"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="third-enemy"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I really like this approach, the code is minimal and $(this) makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @willking, i have edited my answer. Might not be the best approach, but i hope it helps you or teach you something new!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Audio
  // var audioElement = $('audio');
  //  audioElement.attr('src', 'assets/mp3/cantina.mp3');
  //  audioElement.attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  //  audioElement.loop = true; 

  //Objects
  var hansolo = {
    name: "Han Solo",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/7b72d15a85bf468d8af9c5b5699e02ca.png",
  };

  var chewy = {
    name: "Chewy",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/044c70c30f084ba095c35aa7e4451f0c.png",
  };

  var jabba = {
    name: "Jabba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/458ccfc9819f4f8b85116b81584f4eea.png",
  };

  var boba = {
    name: "Boba",
    attack: 10,
    hp: 20,
    counter: 0,
    src: "https://image.prntscr.com/image/85458d08609f4170b5b8cdda58fca07c.png",
  };

  var choices = [hansolo, chewy, jabba, boba];

  var charOptionsRow = $('#charOptions');
  $.each(choices, function(index, choice) {
    // Create a new div.col-lg-3 to be appended to row.
    var charOptionCol = $('<div>')
      .addClass('char-option col-lg-3');

    // Append image to col.
    var charImg = $('<img>')
      .addClass('char-img')
      .attr('src', choice.src);
    charOptionCol.append(charImg);

    // Append text to col.
    var charText = $('<h3>')
      .addClass('char-text')
      .text(choice.name);
    charOptionCol.append(charText);

    // Append column to row.
    charOptionsRow.append(charOptionCol);
  });

  $('.char-img, .char-text').on('click', function() {
    $('#chosen-img').remove();
    $('#chosen').prepend('<img id="chosen-img"/>');
    $('#chosen-img').css({
      'border': '2px solid red'
    }).attr('src', $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src'));
    $('h2', '#chosen').text("You Choose: " + $(this).parent().find('.char-text').text()).removeClass('hidden').show();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, 100);
    //console.log($(this).attr('src'));
    // console.log($(this).parent().find('.char-text').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JQuery Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="max-width:800px;">
    <h1 align="center">Star Wars Game</h1>
    <h2 align="center" id="character-text">Choose your character:</h2>
    <div class="row" id="charOptions" style="max-width:800px;" align="center">
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Choice Header -->
      <div class="col-lg-6 you" id="chosen" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">You</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- First Enemy Header -->
      <div class="col-lg-6 fighting" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="chosen-text" class="hidden">Fighting</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Enemies Header-->
      <div class="col-lg-12" id="enemies" align="center">
        <h2 align="center" id="enemies-text" class="hidden">Your Enemies</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" align="center" style="max-width:800px;">
      <!-- Enemies -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="first-enemy"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="second-enemy"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" align="center">
        <div id="third-enemy"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```